# Проблемы с путями после переноса на хостинг

Tags: php, ftp, hosting

[image]
Перенес сайт на хостинг, но возникла ошибка при подключении файлов из фронконтроллера:

> Warning: require_once(/home/u942040132/public_html/components/Db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u942040132/public_html/index.php on line 19
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/u942040132/public_html/components/Db.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.6/pear') in /home/u942040132/public_html/index.php on line 19
> вот здесь:

```
require_once (ROOT .'/base/ErrorHandler.php');
require_once(ROOT.'/components/Router.php');
require_once(ROOT.'/components/Db.php');
require_once (ROOT .'/config/routes.php');
```

ROOT я о определяю так: `define('ROOT', dirname(FILE));`

Comment: А файл Db.php в папке components точно есть на сервере? Или он не скопировался? Или он не Db.php, а db.php?

Comment: спасибо большое,db с маленькой надо было.уже ничего не вижу ,мозг перегружен